# How can I implement behavior like Spring DispatcherServlet?

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I want create logic like Spring `DispatcherServlet`.

I have one method recevie Wrapper request.

```
public void recevieWrapper(Wrapper wrapper){}
```

And after that I need redirect internal requests from `wrapper` to hadlers methods

```
public void firstInternalrequest(FirstInternalRequest firstInternalRequest){
}

public void secondInternalrequest(SecondInternalRequest secondInternalRequest){
}

public void lastInternalrequest(LastInternalRequest lastInternalRequest){
}
```

What is the name of this approach? What should I read? I can not even google the correct question. I think it's some kind of design pattern?

Comment: Spring implements many design patterns like Factory,Singleton etc .You should search for design patterns used in spring mvc .That might help.Thanks

Comment: It's not very clear on what you are trying to achieve. You could take a look at the source code of DispatcherServlet's doDispatch method and see if it helps. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java

Comment: I think here you want to perform an operation on a group of similar kind of Objects. visitor pattern may be help you.

Comment: You could take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern